# How to make jenkins trigger build failure if tests were failed

Tags: python, jenkins, python-unittest

I have few tests written in Python with unittest module. Tests working properly, but in Jenkins even if test fails, build with this test is still marked as successive. Is there way to check output for python test and return needed result?

Comment: How do you execute your tests via Jenkins?

Comment: Added Python plugin to jenkins, connected GitHub repo with actual test, created new job. In job configuration in build settings set command to:
pip install selenium
python test.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you publish the unit test results in the post build section (If you aren't already, you should), you set the thresholds for failure.
If you don't set thresholds, the build will always fail unless running them returns a non zero exit code.
To always fail the build on any unit test failure, set all failure thresholds to zero.
Note that you can also set thresholds for skipped tests as well.

Comment: Could you, please, provide a bit detailed answer? What and how should I publish?

Comment: Well, thank you! I had to add install unittest-xml-reporting package and added this lines to my test file: 
unittest.main(testRunner=xmlrunner.XMLTestRunner(output='test-reports'))
Actually there was no need to do something in post build section